# Plotting a colormap in Python changes unexpectedly depending on the range of values plotted?

Tags: python, matplotlib, imshow, colormap

I'm using pyplot.imshow to display a colormap with two minimal points with the following code. Running the code however, shows the two minimal points in black but at the wrong location (they should be at (x1,y1) and (x2,y2)). What's more, the location also varies if changing t_max. What am I doing wrong?

```
import numpy
import matplotlib.pyplot as pyplot
import matplotlib.cm as cm

a = 0.1
b = 4
X = 1.1*10**7
x1, y1 = 36, 48*numpy.pi/32
x2, y2 = 49, 57*numpy.pi/32
d1 = (-101872 + X - (X - 2122) * (1+(a*(x1-x2)**2 + (b*(y1-y2))**2)))/((1/(1+(a*(x2-x1)**2 + (b*(y2-y1))**2))) - (1+(a*(x1-x2)**2 + (b*(y1-y2))**2)))
d2 = (X - d1 - 2122)*(1+(a*(x1-x2)**2 + (b*(y1-y2))**2))
def E_density(x, y):
    return X - d1/(1+(a*(x-x1)**2 + (b*(y-y1))**2)) - d2/(1+(a*(x-x2)**2 + (b*(y-y2))**2))

t_min, t_max = 14, 104
phi_min, phi_max = 47*numpy.pi/32, 61*numpy.pi/32
dt = 1
dphi = numpy.pi/128
x_axis = numpy.arange(t_min, t_max, dt)
y_axis = numpy.arange(phi_min, phi_max, dphi)

f = numpy.zeros((len(x_axis), len(y_axis)))
for ix, x in enumerate(x_axis):
    for iy, y in enumerate(y_axis):
        f[ix, iy] = E_density(x, y)

fig1 = pyplot.figure()
im = pyplot.imshow(f, extent = (t_min, t_max, phi_min, phi_max), origin = 'lower', cmap = cm.gray, aspect = 'auto', vmin = 0, vmax = 10**7)
pyplot.colorbar(im, orientation = 'vertical')

pyplot.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have mixed the X and Y axis. Funnily enough I just [answered another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42690279/4124317), where this problem occured.

```
import numpy
import matplotlib.pyplot as pyplot
import matplotlib.cm as cm

a = 0.1
b = 4
X = 1.1*10**7
x1, y1 = 36, 48*numpy.pi/32
x2, y2 = 49, 57*numpy.pi/32
d1 = (-101872 + X - (X - 2122) * (1+(a*(x1-x2)**2 + (b*(y1-y2))**2)))/((1/(1+(a*(x2-x1)**2 + (b*(y2-y1))**2))) - (1+(a*(x1-x2)**2 + (b*(y1-y2))**2)))
d2 = (X - d1 - 2122)*(1+(a*(x1-x2)**2 + (b*(y1-y2))**2))
def E_density(x, y):
    return X - d1/(1+(a*(x-x1)**2 + (b*(y-y1))**2)) - d2/(1+(a*(x-x2)**2 + (b*(y-y2))**2))

t_min, t_max = 14, 104
phi_min, phi_max = 47*numpy.pi/32, 61*numpy.pi/32
dt = 1
dphi = numpy.pi/128
x_axis = numpy.arange(t_min, t_max, dt)
y_axis = numpy.arange(phi_min, phi_max, dphi)

f = numpy.zeros((len(y_axis), len(x_axis)))
for ix, x in enumerate(x_axis):
    for iy, y in enumerate(y_axis):
        f[iy,ix] = E_density(x, y)

fig1 = pyplot.figure()
im = pyplot.imshow(f, extent = (t_min, t_max, phi_min, phi_max), origin = 'lower', cmap = cm.gray, aspect = 'auto', vmin = 0, vmax = 10**7)
pyplot.colorbar(im, orientation = 'vertical')

pyplot.show()
```

[image]